# Hide html element in subscription

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using angular at the minute and I've a check-box that I want to make either visible or hidden based on the result of a subscription to an API call.

My problem is that there is a 'delay' in the checkbox becoming invisible (it is default set to visible). I think this is because I am setting the visibility boolean in the subscription.

Essentially, the subscription is called when a mat-chip selection is made. If the API returns anything, the boolean remains true. If nothing is returned, then it is false. Unfortunately, I have to click away from the mat-chip section for the checkbox to then disappear, it is not instant which is what I would like.

HTML:

```html
<div class="btn-div" style="justify-content: space-between">
    <mat-checkbox color="primary" [formControl]="drilldownSelect" *ngIf="children">Show sector
        breakdown</mat-checkbox>
    <button mat-button (click)="showSectors = !showSectors">
        <mat-icon *ngIf="!showSectors">unfold_more</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="showSectors">unfold_less</mat-icon>
    </button>
</div>
<mat-form-field class="btn-div" *ngIf="showSectors">
    <mat-chip-list #chipList>
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let sector of chosenSectors" [removable]="true" (removed)="removeSector(sector)">
            {{ sector.service_code + ": " + sector.service }}
            <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
        <input placeholder="Sectors" #sectorInput [formControl]="sectorCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
            [matChipInputFor]="chipList" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="true">
    </mat-chip-list>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let sector of filteredSectors | async" [value]="sector" matTooltip={{sector.commodity}}
            [matTooltipPosition]="'after'" [matTooltipShowDelay]="500">
            {{ sector.service_code + ": " + sector.service }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
        this.testMethod(event.option.value.service_code);

    }

testMethod(serviceCode: string) {
        this.hasChildren(serviceCode).subscribe((codes) => {
            codes.length == 0 ? this.children = false : this.children = true;
        });
    }

hasChildren(serviceCode: string): Observable<any> {
        this.serviceCodeAppend = serviceCode + "_";
        console.log(this.serviceCodeAppend);
        return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.backendService.url}/table?code=like.${this.serviceCodeAppend}`).pipe(
            catchError(error => {
                this.backendService.handleError(error);
                return of({});
            })
        ).pipe(shareReplay(1));
    }
```

The above should contain all the relevant code that makes the checkbox disappear when clicked away from but doesn't work 'instantly'

Comment: If the visibility depends on an API response it is normal that it has some delay... what do you mean by "Unfortunately, I have to click away from the mat-chip section for the checkbox to then disappear"?

Comment: This is part of a larger form. When I select a value in the mat-chip-list that results in the value of this.children being set to false, this is done pretty instantly. However, the visibility does not update until I click a different section of the form.

Comment: Are you using changeDetection in your ts file?

Comment: *it is not instant which is what I would like* you can't do this. Your making an api call, this api call takes time, so this is impossible

Comment: If what you mean by "instant" is that you actually have to take another action DESPITE the response of your API already arrived, then you should take a look at triggering changeDetection from inside your component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it looks like you're having issues with Angular's change detection not triggering when you want, you can do this manually.

Inject in your constructor

```js
constructor(cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

then inside your `subscribe`

```js
  this.service.apiCall().subscribe(response => {
    // Rest of your code
    cdRef.detectChanges();
  });
```